# How do I sort a dictionary by value with the key as a tie-breaker?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

For instance, if I sorted:

```
{3:4, 4:5, 5:5, 7:2}
```

I would expect:

```
{7:2, 3:4, 4:5, 5:5}
```

Note:
This is not a duplicate of other 'how to sort a dictionary' questions because they do not show how to use the key as a tie-breaker.

Related:

[How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

[Python 3 list sorting with a tie-breaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54300715/python-3-list-sorting-with-a-tie-breaker)

Comment: See the [The Old Way Using Decorate-Sort-Undecorate](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#the-old-way-using-decorate-sort-undecorate) section of the [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sorting-how-to) in the fine documentation.  It (also) explains why the technique described is not often needed because of Python's key-functions.

Answer (score 7):

You can sort `d.items()`. Since it's key-value tuples, the second elements are values and first elements are keys.

```
out = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0])))
```

Output:

```
{7: 2, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 5}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort dict by it's values and then by keys as a tie breaker then use following code :

> here key = lambda consist of **dict value = (x[1])** as well as **dict key = (x[0])**

```
d= {3:4, 4:5, 5:5, 7:2}    # or any other dict

sorted(d.items() , key=lambda x: [x[1],x[0]])

o/p : [(7, 2), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 5)]
```

So you can change the sequence as per your need for example if you want to sort by keys first then values then use this:

```
sorted(d.items() , key=lambda x: [x[0],x[1]])
```

If you want the sorting in reverse for values and then by keys then use this:

```
    sorted(d.items() , key=lambda x: [-x[1],-x[0]])
```

If you want to reverse any one of the values or keys then use negative sign accordingly

> One last thing [] or () both work fine in lambda function

```
sorted(d.items() , key=lambda x: (x[1],x[0]))

sorted(d.items() , key=lambda x: [x[1],x[0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If the keys are already in order, you can leverage the fact that Python's sort is stable (keeps original order for same value sort key):

```
{k:d[k] for k in sorted(d,key=d.get)}

{7: 2, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 5}
```